# find start date and end date of next 12 months in javascript and insert in gridview with 12 rows

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a gridview called gvFiscalPeriod. I have a textbox where user can enter a date for example '1/11/2022' (start date). Based on the date, I should be able to generate for  next 12 months, where each row is a month with start date and end date.

Eg:

```
id |  StartDate  |   EndDate
1  |  1/11/2022  |   30/11/2022
2  |  1/12/2022  |   31/12/2022
3  |  1/1/2023   |   31/01/2023
```

This is my script:

```
<table id="gvFiscalPeriod" class="display nowrap table table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer;display:none">
                @{
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th class="th-label-vertical-align">From Date</th>
                            <th class="th-label-vertical-align">To Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{
                            int i = 0;
                            colArray = new string[] { "ID","FromDate", "ToDate"};
                            foreach (var item in Model.PeriodList)
                            {

                                _colCount = 0;
                                foreach (var colName in colArray)
                                {
                                    if (_colCount == 0)
                                    {@:<tr>
                                        }
                                        if (chkColExist(item, colName.Replace(" ", "")))
                                        {
                                            var colProperty = item.GetType().GetProperty(colName.Replace(" ", ""));
                                            if (colProperty != null)
                                            {
                                                dynamic colValue = colProperty.GetValue(item, null);
                                                if (colProperty.Name.ToString() == "FromDate" || colProperty.Name.ToString() == "ToDate")
                                                {
                                                    colValue = colValue.ToString(Model.GlobalFormatDateList[0].Value);
                                                }
                                               
                                                else if (colName == "ID")
                                                {
                                                    <td id="chk-ID-@i"> @Html.Raw(colValue) </td>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <td> @Html.Raw(colValue) </td>
                                                }
                                                _colCount++;
                                            }


                                        }
                                        if (_colCount == colArray.Length)
                                        {@:</tr>
                                    }
                                }
                                i++;
                            }

                            gvColumnLength = colArray.Length.ToString();
                        }
                    </tbody>
                }
            </table>

    function SaveAddFiscalPeriod() {
        gvDT.row.add([
            ID,
            $(StartDate).val(),
            $(EndDate).val()
           
        ]).draw(false);

        gvDT.columns.adjust().draw();
    }
});
```

But this script is only adding one row, but I want to add 12 rows with startdate and enddate

Comment: Is this correct -> colArray = new string[] { "ID""FromDate", "ToDate"}; Did you mean to not include a comma between ID and FromDate?

Comment: RossBin , Amended, my bad

Comment: Another thing, you may want to check if you should be  calling the incrementor _colCount++, even when the data is invalid.

Comment: the table is displaying correctly, but from an input lookup , user will input a date, and I should add next 12 rows based on the date

Comment: can't u put a table of 12 row and hide it. When user click the button, u get Javascript to insert the value accordingly and display the table. Simple right?